# laravel 5.1 about Resetting Passwords

Tags: laravel

If I didn't log in , I can go to Route:http://localhost:8000/password/email,and show the view.
But, when I logged in,it go to Route:http://localhost:8000/home with an error

NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 161:

I think it should also return view password.blade.php,but it did not

How to solve？

Comment: Can add more code including your related controllers?

Answer (score 0):

After a successful authentication the default action is to go to '/home', if there isn't the associated routes or views (controllers are provided by default) it causes the 'NotFoundHttpException' you mentioned.

If you haven't done already, you need to create the routes and views . The [documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/authentication#included-routing) mentions what you need to include.

If these exist already and you're wondering how to change the default behaviour of redirecting the user to '/home', you you can customize the post-authentication redirect location by defining a redirectPath property on the AuthController:

```
protected $redirectPath = '/dashboard';
```

Comment: i have done what you said. I mean when i logged in ,it does not work.

Comment: and if i log out ,it is ok

Comment: As Adrian said above, can you add more code including your related controllers, routes and try to expand on what you are trying to do.

Comment: `Route::get('password/email', 'Auth\PasswordController@getEmail');
Route::post('password/email', 'Auth\PasswordController@postEmail');
Route::get('password/reset/{token}', 'Auth\PasswordController@getReset');
Route::post('password/reset', 'Auth\PasswordController@postReset');`

Comment: PasswordController  `protected $redirectTo = '/';`

Comment: and ResetsPasswords `public function getEmail()
    {
        return view('auth.password');
    }`

Comment: viem/password.blade.php  `<form method="POST" action="/password/email">
    {!! csrf_field() !!}
    <div>
        Email
        <input type="email" name="email" value="{{ old('email') }}">
    </div>
    <div>
        <button type="submit">
            Send Password Reset Link
        </button>
    </div>
</form>`

Comment: The auth controllers look for the view at
    'resources/views/auth/password.blade.php' - 
It looks like you have put it at 'resources/views/password.blade.php' instead, so it can't find the correct view. If the user is already logged in, they get redirected to home - or whatever is set in the $redirectPath.